# Ball Playing on Shabbbos

Tags: shabbat, games-toys, halacha, sport-athletics

Is one allowed to play ball on Shabbos?

Comment: Check out this link: [Playing Ball On Shabbat And Yom Tov, Rabbi Saul J. Berman](http://www.edah.org/backend/coldfusion/search/document.cfm?title=Playing%20Ball%20On%20Shabbat%20And%20Yom%20Tov&hyperlink=Playing_Ball_On_Shabbat.html&type=JournalArticle&category=Contemporary%20Jewish%20and%20Halakhic%20Issues&authortitle=Rabbi&firstname=Saul%20J.&lastname=Berman&pubsource=The%20Edah%20Journal%20Volume%201:1&authorid=169&pdfattachment=berman.pdf)

Comment: this link really covers it all, I just wanted to add that this issue is also discussed in Volume 3 Issue 15 of Halachically speaking (http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume3/Issue15.pdf), titled "Toys and Games on Shabbos", and brings a couple of the poskim from our generation as well.

Comment: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=6/13/2012
this link will provide a good deal of sources

Comment: Especially as the link mis http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue15.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The Midrash (Eichah Rabbah 2:4) says that this is why Tur Shimon was destroyed:

> טור שמעון הוה מפיק תלת מאה גרבין ולמה חרב אי תימא מן הזנות והלא לא היתה אלא ריבה אחת והוציאוה משם אמר רב הונא משום שהיו משחקים בכדור בשבת
>
> Tur Shimon would distribute 300 baskets to the poor. Why was it destroyed? If it’s because of harlotry, there was just one [such] girl in that town, and they had sent her out from there! R’ Huna said: because they would play ball on Shabbos.

It should be noted that Yerushalmi Taanis 4:5 cites this story in regard to Beitar, and it cites it without the word בשבת. Karban HaEidah explains that either the text should be emended to match the Midrash, or it means that it was destroyed because they played ball *regularly*, i.e. instead of learning Torah.